# Can't enable NFC on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, nfc

For some reason I am unable to enable / use NFC on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300).

When I got the phone, it did work. A month ago, I wanted to use it again and it did not work. I am currently using a non-original battery in my phone, but I swapped the battery with one I've tested NFC with, and it still didn't work, and NFC with my battery in another S3 does work, so it can't be because of the non-original battery.

When the issue first appeared, I was using stock firmware (Android 4.3). After I flashed my phone to Cyanogenmod 13 (including wiping all caches, system, data, ...), I tried again and NFC still does not work. When I flip the NFC switch from off to on, it stays in the 'on' position, but it is disabled (gray), I can't switch it off or on again until I restart the phone, and any app trying to use NFC is telling me to enable it.

There is no warranty on the phone any more, first, because it's too old, second, because there is root+CM on it.

Is there any way I could get NFC to work again? Any "NFC reset" or whatever? Or would I have to buy a new phone? Could this be any software issue or is my NFC module probably broken?

EDIT: `logcat` says `2952  5203 E NFC-HCI : Could not open /vendor/firmware/libpn544_fw.so`. But that file does exist ...

Comment: Hmmmmm. Someone else is having this issue? I have it too man. I never had NFC access in the first place. Ill investigate lthe details.